# R Programming: Expression Computation

Tags: r, vectorization

Anyone help me how to solve the following expression:

> 8 x 8
>
> 8 x 88
>
> 8 x 888
>
> 8 x 8888
>
> 8 x 88888

I am to use R programming to do the computation. But is there a way I can use R code for this computation with a single R expression that has no commas and braces (i.e. the use of , and {}).

Anyway to do this via vectorization, without using condition statements (if, while, for)?

Comment: What is the desired output? A vector of 5 elements with each of those products? Why such odd restrictions? Is this a homework assignment or something?

Comment: Output is the result of those products. But I need to know the implementations for such. Yeah a tricky tutorial question that I've been stuck on for a while.

Comment: Well, do you see a pattern at all? Can you represent that mathematically? For homework questions, it's important you've at least shown some effort to solve the problem. Do you have code that *almost* works? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I've got a problem more on generating the multiple 8's. I've tried a code block but seems to be inefficient: n = 8, as.numeric(n); n = paste(n, 8, sep=""), as.numeric(n). This produces output 8 and 88 but seems inefficient to call n multiple times.

Comment: And it also uses commas. I'll give you a hit: think of sums using powers of 10 to create eights in different decimal places.

Comment: @thelatemail maybe its not supposed to be a complex expression. just sequence generation, or applying summaries maybe?

Comment: This is closer but still has one comma: ```sapply(1:5, function(x) 8 * floor(0.88888 * 10 ^ x))```

Comment: Actually the last one could be cone without a comma (or a period) but it still uses a "brace", the English word for parenthesis. See the expression I evaluate in my first call below.

Answer (score 10):

The sequence of ones:

```
cumsum(10^(0:4))
## [1]     1    11   111  1111 11111
```

Eights:

```
8 * cumsum(10^(0:4))
## [1]     8    88   888  8888 88888
```

Times eight:

```
 8 * 8 * cumsum(10^(0:4))
## [1]     64    704   7104  71104 711104
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that interested in playing within the rules not to use commas or parentheses:

```
> sapply(trunc(( 8/9)*10^(1:6) ) , 
           function(y) substitute( 8 * y, list(y=y) ) )
[[1]]
8 * 8

[[2]]
8 * 88

[[3]]
8 * 888

[[4]]
8 * 8888

[[5]]
8 * 88888

[[6]]
8 * 888888
```

And to give the results of those expressions:

```
> lapply( sapply(trunc(( 8/9)*10^(1:6) ) , 
                   function(y) substitute( 8 * y, list(y=y) ) ), eval)
[[1]]
[1] 64

[[2]]
[1] 704

[[3]]
[1] 7104

[[4]]
[1] 71104

[[5]]
[1] 711104

[[6]]
[1] 7111104
```

Comment: living on the edge i see. thanks for your input anyway

Answer (score 0):

*I think you should consider what you really want, because there are several ways to do this. Here are some examples:*

#**Example 1 (All input parameters for free):**

```
 result <- (n_ini=scan(,what=numeric(),1))*
           (n_end=scan(,what=numeric(),1))*
           (((cumsum(10^((x_init=scan(,what=numeric(),1)):
              (x_count=scan(,what=numeric(),1)))))))
```

**Example 2(A number multiplied by itself a certain number of times):**

*Be careful not to copy and paste the entire code for it to work you have to run it for parts ...*

```
n_self <- scan(n=1)  
print ("Press [enter] to continue")  
x_countstop <- scan(n=1)  
result2 <- n_self*n_self*(cumsum(10^((0):(x_countstop))))  
result2
```

*There are countless ways to do it, but I hope that these will serve as something.*

Best Regards